# Find documents with two words in a given proximity in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe with a variable called `text`, which includes news transcripts. I want to identify transcripts that include the word "Republican" OR "Democrat" AND one of a list of words in a given proximity (let's say within 5 words). For example, if one of the list of words is "Congress," I want to pick up these transcripts:

- "Republicans in Congress today voted on a bill." (proximity < 5)
- "Democrats in Congress today voted on a bill." (proximity < 5)

And I do NOT want to pick up these transcripts:

- "Republicans today passed a bill to allocate funds for Congress." (proximity > 5)
- "Democrats today passed a bill to allocate funds for Congress." (proximity > 5)

I can match the list of words without the proximity restraint like this:

```
transcripts <- data.frame(text=c("Republicans in congress today voted on a bill","Republicans today passed a bill to allocate funds for Congress")
dictionary <- data.frame(word=c("Congress","Capitol"))

transcripts_subset <- transcripts %>%
  filter(grepl(paste(dictionary$word, collapse="|"), text))
```

and I tried looking up the regex to do this correctly, but it throws an error:

```
transcripts_subset <- transcripts %>%
   filter(grepl("\b(paste(dictionary$dehumanizing, collapse="|"))(?:\\W+\\w+){0,5}?\\W+(Republican|Democrat)\b", text))
```

```
Error in "\b ..." : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dplyr` filter code looks fine, so here is just the regex bit:

```r
dictionary <- data.frame(word=c("Congress","Capitol"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

pattern_after  <- paste0("\\b(", paste0(dictionary$word, collapse="|"), ")\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,5}?(Republican(s)*|Democrat(s)*)")
pattern_before <- paste0("\\b(Republican(s)*|Democrat(s)*)\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,5}?", paste0(dictionary$word, collapse="|"), collapse="|")
pattern <- paste0(c(pattern_after, pattern_before), collapse="|")
pattern
#> [1] "\\b(Congress|Capitol)\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,5}?(Republican(s)*|Democrat(s)*)|\\b(Republican(s)*|Democrat(s)*)\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,5}?Congress|Capitol"


grepl(pattern, "Republicans in congress today voted on a bill", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE

grepl(pattern, "Democrats today passed a bill to allocate funds for Congress", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
#> [1] FALSE

grepl(pattern, "A Democrat in Congress", perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

To disect this, the regex to find two words sperated by 0 to 5 other words in`R` is

`"\\bword1\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){0,5}word2"`

- `\\b` is a word boundary, meaning whitespace, punctuation or the end of a string.
- `\\W+` is one or more Non-word characters (i.e., word boundaries or something else)
- `\\w+` means Word one or more characters i.e. a sequence of letters or numbers
- `(?:\\w+\\W+)` is a a group consisting of word characters followed by non word characters (i.e., words with spaces)
- `{0,5}` indicates the group is matched between 0 and 5 times

You need to set `perl = TRUE` for this to work. `"Republican(s)*"` means that "Republican" either followed by an "s" or not. The two separate pattern s are to make sure it works no matter if the word or Republican/Democrat are mentioned first.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following which splits you string and tests with `grep` where the words in the dictionary are located. It they are `<5` they are selected.

```
transcripts[sapply(strsplit(as.character(transcripts$text), " "), grep
 , pattern=paste(dictionary$word, collapse="|"), ignore.case = TRUE) < 5,]
#[1] Republicans in congress today voted on a bill

#Or using sub to get the first 5 words
transcripts[sapply(sub("((\\S+\\s*){0,5}).*", "\\1", transcripts$text), grepl
 , pattern=paste(dictionary$word, collapse="|"), ignore.case = TRUE),]
```

Comment: would you be willing to format your code so it's not one super-long line ... ?